# Black screen with SGS1

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, galaxy

I'm working on a game which runs quite well on a lot of Android devices (Lexus 7, SG ACe, HTC Desire ...). But especially for SGS1, I can't get better than a black screen.
After investigating a lot into the whole code, I think that the problem is located in my shader code. Compilation is ok, link too, but I hear about some incompatibility between different GPU (here http://www.jpct.net/forum2/index.php/topic,2833.15.html for example)

Here's the shader code :

[VERTEX]

```
uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;    // Ortho matrix
attribute vec2 vPosition;   // Vertex position
void main(){
    gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vec4(vPosition, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

[FRAGMENT]

```
precision mediump float;
uniform lowp vec4 CurColor;
void main(){
    gl_FragColor = CurColor;
}
```

Maybe something is obviously wrong in this, even if it is very basic ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out. I had 2 problems :

1) PowerVR seems to dislike the 'lowp' qualifier for uniform

2) in other shaders, I had 'vec4' for vPosition, although I pass only 2 components by vertex (X,Y). The strange thing about that is : why other GPUs could work with such mistakes ? A checker like the one provided by mali (malideveloper.com/developer-resources/tools/…) would be extremely refreshing for PowerVR!

Answer (score 0):

Here is some advice:

- Try to see if there are any LogCat errors
- See if `glGetError()` returns something different from 0
- Change the clear color to see if the screen remains black, if it changes, then your objects are invisible

Comment me after you try some of these.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, and: screen is all green. glGetError() returned many errors in my phone (Samsung Ace:GT-S5830) that I fixed, but none on the SGS1. It's very weird ! And there's no errors in LogCat (I can post a sample if you want). Any other ideas ?

Comment: I've tried a lot of things, and reduced my game to the minimum, with one simple shader. And screen is always empty ! I was wondering about the texture enabling by GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D) : is it necessary with opengl es 2 ? Can this line crash the whole process ?

Comment: No, it's necessary. Does your color change when you change the clearing color?

Comment: Yes, the color of the entire screen changes. Thank you, but I finally figured it out. Answer is above.